# Retrieving data from a list of uid's

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am dabbling around some Android/Firebase stuff and have run into a problem and can't seem to find the solution online; which is why I'm here in hopes of getting some help. I am trying to retrieve data uside the messages node that has the following database structure:

`-root
    -messages
        -uid(unique user ID)
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
        -uid(unique user ID)
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
        -uid(unique user ID)
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
            -unique message id(via push)
                -description: a brief description about this first message.
                -title: the first title
    -users
        -uid(unique user ID)
            -active: true
            -fname: Robert
            -lname: Smith
            -email: test1@gmail.com
        -uid(unique user ID)
            -active: true
            -fname: Douglas
            -lname: Crockford
            -email: test2@firebase.com
        -uid(unique user ID)
            -active: true
            -fname: John
            -lname: Doe
            -email: test3@firebase.com`

here's what my class MyListingsActivity that extends ListActivity looks like briefly:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("firebase-url/posts");

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Posts>(this, Posts.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mFirebaseRef.child("uid - unique user ID")){

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Posts model) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getTitle());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getDescription());
        }
    };
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String postTitle = ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
    String postDesc = ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListView.class);
    i.putExtra("postTitle", postTitle);
    i.putExtra("postDescription", postDesc);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

each message corresponds to a particular existing user.

I'd like to retrieve all the data inside messages and make a list view out of it. I am able to currently retrieve data for a particular user using the uid but not for every user.

Here's my code and Firebaseadapter

```
mFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Posts post = postSnapshot.getValue(Posts.class);
                System.out.println(post.getTitle() + " - " + post.getDescription());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Posts>(this, Posts.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mFirebaseRef.child(user id)){
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Posts model) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getTitle());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getDescription());
        }
    };
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Thank You!

Comment: One way to read an entire node in is with addValueEventListener - it reads the entire contents of a database node. In this case you want to retrieve all of the data inside messages (at one time?). It will populate a snapshot (using onDataChange) that you can iterate over to create your list view. Do you need something more?  Oh - and reading in everything in the node can be tricky, depending on how much data it is. 1 Million items would probably go beyond memory storage.

Comment: Hi Jay thanks for the reply. I am using the firebaseadapter and have been having a difficult time retrieving the data and adding it onto the adapter. I've added some code to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to load your messages data directly using addValueEventListener, but without using the UID of the users. For example, if you were using the format `"messages/{uid}"` to get `mFirebaseRef`, you should just use `"messages"`.

This way, all the content under messages will get loaded in your snapshot. Now you won't be able to cast this into a proper model or POJO yet, since it's not the exact format of your data model (Post),but it's a Map. So you'll have to iterate it to get your data model. Something like the following code.

```
DatabaseReference mFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");
mFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<String, Map> map = (Map<String, Map>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        mMessages.clear();
        if (map != null) {
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {//keys will be uid
            Map<String, Map> map2 = map.get(key);
            for (String key2 : map2.keySet()) {
                Map<String, Map> map3 = map2.get(key2); //this map will be your Data Model
                mMessages.add(new Posts(map3)); //add a constructor in the Posts class to get values from the map3 and set the properties or you can convert it into Gson and generate your data model directly from the gson string.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Don't blame me for the complex code, your database structure is responsible for that ;-)
PPS: There could be a more elegant or optimized way to do that, however I would have done it this way only.